# Renaming Multiple Files at Once in a Directory

Tags: python, directory, rename

I am attempting to take a file name such as 'OP 40 856101.txt' from a directory, remove the .txt, set each single word to a specific variable, then reorder the filename based on a required order such as '856101 OP 040'. Below is my code:

```
import os 


dir = 'C:/Users/brian/Documents/Moeller'
orig = os.listdir(dir)                  #original names of the files in the folder

for orig_name in orig:             #This loop splits each file name into a list of stings containing each word
    f = os.path.splitext(orig_name)[0]
    sep = f.split()             #Separation is done by a space
    for t in sep:           #Loops across each list of strings into an if statement that saves each part to a specific variable
        #print(t)
        if t.isalpha() and len(t) == 3:
            wc = t
        elif len(t) > 3 and len(t) < 6:
            wc = t
        elif t == 'OP':
            op = t
        elif len(t) >= 4:
            pnum = t
        else:
            opnum = t
            if len(opnum) == 2:
                opnum = '0' + opnum
    new_nam = '%s %s %s %s' % (pnum,op,opnum, wc)          #This is the variable that contain the text for the new name

    print("The orig filename is %r, the new filename is %r" % (orig_name, new_nam))
    os.rename(orig_name, new_nam)
```

However I am getting an error with my last for loop where I attempt to rename each file in the directory.

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '150 856101 OP CLEAN.txt' -> '856101 OP 150 CLEAN'
```

The code runs perfectly until the os.rename() command, if I print out the variable new_nam, it prints out the correct naming order for all of the files in the directory. Seems like it cannot find the original file though to replace the filename to the string in new_nam. I assume it is a directory issue, however I am newer to python and can't seem to figure where to edit my code. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (just changed the last line):

```
       os.rename(os.path.join(dir,orig_name), os.path.join(dir,new_nam))
```

You need to tell Python the actual path of the file to rename - otherwise, it looks only in the directory containing this file.

Incidentally, it's better not to use `dir` as a variable name, because that's the name of a built-in.

Comment: Worked! Thank you!!